# list only stops once the element of the list is the number 7

Tags: python, list, element, sublist

I want to write  a code that  contains a sublist , that only stops once the element of the list is a certain number , for example 9.

I´ve already tried using different operators , if statements .

```
def sublist (list): 
return [x for x in list if x  <9]
```

`[7,8,3,2,4,9,51]`
the  output for the list above should be :
`[7,8,3,2,4]`

Comment: You need to use normal for loop and break

Comment: I got the result you expect from the sample input `[ x for x in [7, 8, 3, 2, 4, 9, 51] if x < 9]` - the result is `[7, 8, 3, 2, 4]`

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions really are for making mapping/filtering combinations. If the length depends on some previous state in the iteration, you're better off with a for-loop, it will be more readable. However, this is a use-case for `itertools.takewhile`. Here is a functional approach to this task, just for fun, some may even consider it readable:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> from functools import partial
>>> import operator as op
>>> list(takewhile(partial(op.ne, 9), [7,8,3,2,4,9,51]))
[7, 8, 3, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, it's not a good idea to use python keywords like `list` as variable.

The list comprehension `[x for x in list if x < 9]` filters out elements less than 9, but it won't stop when it encounters a 9, instead it will go over the entire list

Example:

```
li = [7,8,3,2,4,9,51,8,7]
print([x for x in li if x < 9])
```

The output is

```
[7, 8, 3, 2, 4, 8, 7]
```

To achieve what you are looking for, you want a for loop which breaks when it encounters a given element (9 in your case)

```
li = [7,8,3,2,4,9,51]

res = []
item = 9

#Iterate over the list
for x in li:
    #If item is encountered, break the loop
    if x == item:
        break
    #Append item to list
    res.append(x)

print(res)
```

The output is

```
[7, 8, 3, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iter()` builtin with sentinel value ([official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#iter))

```
l = [7,8,3,2,4,9,51]
sublist = [*iter(lambda i=iter(l): next(i), 9)]
print(sublist)
```

Prints:

```
[7, 8, 3, 2, 4]
```