# Create a sublist that only contains all the numbers of a list until it reaches a certain number

Tags: python, function

I want to write a code , that  contains a while loop that only stops once the element of the list is the number 9. What is returned is a list of all of the numbers up until it reaches 9. So what it shouldn´t do : have all numbers except 9 , or all numbers that are smaller / bigger than 9 . It should just contain all numbers of a list untill the list reaches 7 . (See example below)

different operators

```py
def hello (list):
    return[ x for x in [7, 8, 3, 2, 4, 9, 51] if x < 9]
```

```py
def check_nums (list):
    return [x for x in list if x >9]
```

i expected the output of for example  [0,2,4,9,2,3,6,8,12,14,7,9,10,8,3] to be
 [0, 2, 4, 9, 2, 3, 6, 8, 12, 14] .

Comment: Go ahead @SUSIE, what's stopping you?

Comment: You're examples seem wrong/incoherent. Also there's no point in defining a function if you're using prefixed lists/parameters

Comment: What do you mean  Reblochon Masque?

Comment: _A code that contains a while loop_: your examples don't have it and why do you need it?

Comment: I don´t need it , I just thought it would help the code ,or that it was necessary to achieve the output I want

Comment: You have asked the same question 3 times already

Comment: I mean don't ask us to do something you have not tried yourself; then, in case you are having difficulties, ask, with a description of the specific problem you faced.

Comment: you already asked this question --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538963/list-only-stops-once-the-element-of-the-list-is-the-number-7 stop spamming with the same question

Comment: guys please stop "attacking " me  , I asked the question to get some help , because I don´t get it and trust me  I´ve tried , not to get so agressive comments .

Comment: And the question is different

Comment: otherwise I wouldn´t ask , that would kind of pointless

Comment: no one is attacking you, this website is not meant to have the same questions asked, regardless of your intentions. please make a conscious effort to understand the answers provided in your previous question and refer to the python docs to get a better understanding, it sounds like you are not grasping certain fundamentals

Answer (score 2):

How about you make a sublist out of the initial array from 0 to the first occurrence of 9.

```
>>> l = [7, 8, 3, 2, 4, 9, 51, 20, 30, 9]
>>> l.index(9)
5
>>> l[:l.index(9)]
[7, 8, 3, 2, 4]
```